# Can't get buttons in custom layout to return a minimal width measurement with WRAP_CONTENT

Tags: android-layout, android

I created a custom flow layout class to lay out a series of buttons of equal height and various widths depending on what text each button displays. Each row contains as many buttons as possible, and any remaining space is distributed evenly to fill up the row. This generally works, but I can't get the buttons to be just small enough to fit their text, and as a result most of the buttons are exactly the same size.

This is how I'm creating the button and adding it to the flow:

```
        Button button = new Button(this);

        button.setMinimumWidth(0);
        button.setText(eventType.get("name").asString());
        button.setAllCaps(false);
        button.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        eventTypeFlow.addView(button);
```

In the layout class' onLayout, I measure each button like this:

```
        View child = getChildAt(childIndex);
        measureChild(child, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(clientWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(clientHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));

        int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
        int childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();
```

But unless the text in the button is especially long, the width is always the same (264 in my case). I tried creating a linear layout XML with the button in it, setting minimum width to 0 and layout:width to wrap_content and that way the button is smaller, but when I distribute the extra space the linear layout grows, not the button.

Is there a way to get the buttons to return a smaller measurement when adding them directly to the custom layout?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a LinearLayout using the layout_weight attribute. Give each button equal weight (1) and set your android:width attribute to 0dp.

[Linear Layout layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight)

More on LinearLayout's LayoutParams can be [found here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: As I outlined in my post I already tried a LinearLayout, but your answer gave me an idea. I added it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @NirArbel Well, you said you tried a LinearLayout, but never mentioned using the layout_weight attribute which would have distributed the space evenly among all buttons. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working is inflating the same linear layout XML I described in my question, then removing the button from the linear layout and adding it directly to my custom layout. Not very elegant, but it's the only thing I found that gets those buttons to be smaller.